# MultiChoiceModeListener support for Android API versions older than 11

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have a fragment(v4 support library) which implements the `MultiChoiceModeListener` interface. But i have defined `android:minSdkVersion="7"` in my manifest. So my fragment class shows me the error :

```
Class requires API level 11 (current min is 7): android.widget.AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener
```

On solution is to use `@SuppressLint("NewApi")`. Although the app would compile successfully, my guess is it would cause the app to crash in older Android versions.

So is it possible to not have the app fail in older Android versions, while still have the `MultiChoiceModeListener` interface implemented for newer versions ? Or do i need to have two different versions of my app or fragment or something on those lines?

Comment: As that is a above level 11 API only you either drop whatever functionality you implemented with it on lower versions or you provide your own implementation. `MultiChoiceModeListener` is a custom implementation for `ActionMode.Callback`, it shouldn't be too hard to implement it on your own for lower platform versions.

Comment: That's precisely what i am looking for. How do i drop the functionality for older versions i.e. How do i tell the app to ignore the interface implementation?

Comment: Do you want to just do nothing on lower versions, drop all the functionality currently implemented on that listener? If yes, then simply wrap setting the `MultiChoiceModeListener` on the `ListView` in a `if` clause(you may also need a @TargetAPI annotation on that class).

Comment: got it thanks. If you want to add it as answer, i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So is it possible to not have the app fail in older Android versions,
>   while still have the MultiChoiceModeListener interface implemented for
>   newer versions ?

`MultiChoiceModeListener` is a class introduced in `HoneyComb`(API level 11) together with the `ActionBar` APIs. Unfortunately, not like the `ActionBar`, this class doesn't have a counterpart in the support library to provide its functionality on lower versions of android. You are left with two choices, you either drop the functionality or you provide your own similar implementation on lower versions that don't support it.

To drop the functionality on lower versions you just need an if clause wrapping the code where you set the listener:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    // we are on HoneyComb or above so its safe to use
    listView.setMultichoiceModeListener(...);
}
```

Comment: But many apps provide multi choice option in APIs < 11. How is it possible? Please suggest something, I wanna use multiChoiceModeListener for my API<11